# PHP MySQL Display Joined and non- Joined Records

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with not been able to display all records from table1.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 and 2 and I want to display all the records from table 1 (Even if some records donly exists on table1 and no reference in table2)

This is what I am trying and I have 2 recording in Table1 but it's only displaying 1.

1 record is joined by the name_id on table1 and table2 and the other record only exists on table1 BUT I need to display both.

Here is the query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  

    table1.name_id, 
    table2.name_id, 

    FROM `table1`

    LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table1.name_id=table2.name_id 

");
```

How can I get it so it will display all the records from table1 (The one's that are join and the ones that are not too) ?

Comment: I think if you use LEFT OUTER JOIN it will display NULL for missing table2 values.

Comment: also syntax error `table2.name_id,`

Comment: yeah, this IS how - just without that extra comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "JOIN" to fetch data from both table as

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  table1.name_id, table2.name_id FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`name_id`=`table2`.`name_id` ");
```